# mysql avg function not returning all records

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using following query

```
select 
    *, 
    dealer.id As dealerID, 
    services.id as serviceID 
from services 
LEFT JOIN dealer 
    on services.dealer=dealer.id 
LEFT JOIN reviews 
    ON reviews.dealer_id=dealer.id 
where services.brand_id = '9' and 
    services.model_id='107' and 
    services.petrol > 0 
ORDER BY services.total asc , 
AVG(reviews.rating) desc
```

I have 6 records and it should display 6 records instead its displaying only 1. When i remove AVG(reviews.rating) desc. It display all records.

## mysql tables are

services

1. dealer
2. brand_id
3. model_id
4. petrol
5. id
6. total

dealer

1. id
2. name

reviews

1. id
2. dealer_id
3. rating

I am not sure where i am doing mistake. If some can help.

Comment: Learn how to use `AVG()`.  The statement won't even run.

Comment: you need  to group by some field otherwise it will take average of whole data

Comment: Learn to write a proper code as well.  The code above doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @Eric: The statement will run, it just will average all rows resulting in a single row in the result. as sumit says, it needs a group by that includes all of the rows.

Comment: I am trying to load avg ratings of a dealer which provide services in a specific model and brand and fuel type.  I have used following statement also select *, dealer.id As dealerID, services.id as serviceID, AVG(rating) AS avgRating from services LEFT JOIN dealer on services.dealer=dealer.id LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.dealer_id=dealer.id where services.brand_id = '9' and services.model_id='107' and services.petrol > 0 ORDER BY services.total desc , avgRating asc

Comment: @SloanThrasher Probably in `MySQL`.  Won't work in any other dbms.

Comment: The working query is select *, dealer.id As dealerID, services.id as serviceID, AVG(reviews.rating) AS avgRating from services LEFT JOIN dealer on services.dealer=dealer.id LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.dealer_id=dealer.id where services.brand_id = '9' and services.model_id='107' and services.petrol > 0 GROUP BY dealer.id ORDER BY services.total asc , avgRating desc

Comment: @danny Use a proper `GROUP BY`.    Columns `services.id`, whatever in `*` must also be in `GROUP BY`.  Also `*` is not valid in statement with `GROUP BY`.  List your columns.

Answer (score 1):

`avg()` is an *aggregation* function.  That is, it takes data from multiple rows and summarizes it.

Without a `group by`, the query is an aggregation query over all the data.  Such a query always returns exactly one row.

Most databases would return an error when you use `select *`, use an aggregation function, and have no `group by`.  MySQL has a (mis)feature where this syntax is allowed (although on the newest versions, the default settings disallow this).

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but `avg()` doesn't make sense in this context.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
ORDER BY services.total asc, reviews.rating desc
```

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned `AVG()` is aggregate ftn, so I have changed the `desc` of your `order by` to include to select the average values.

For future reference:

Providing snippets of raw data also helps. Creating an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) helps even more

```
   select 
        *, 
        dealer.id As dealerID, 
        services.id as serviceID 
    from services 
    LEFT JOIN dealer 
        on services.dealer=dealer.id 
    LEFT JOIN reviews 
        ON reviews.dealer_id=dealer.id 
    where services.brand_id = '9' and 
        services.model_id='107' and 
        services.petrol > 0 
    ORDER BY services.total asc , 
    (SELECT AVG(r2.rating) FROM reviews r2 RIGHT JOIN ON r2.dealer_id=dealer.id)   desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    AVG(c.rating) AS `avg__rating`,
    b.id AS dealerID, 
    a.id AS serviceID 
FROM services a
LEFT JOIN dealer b
    on a.dealer = b.id 
LEFT JOIN reviews c
    ON c.dealer_id = b.id 
WHERE a.brand_id = '9' and 
    a.model_id='107' and 
    a.petrol > 0 
GROUP BY a.dealer, a.brand_id, a.model_id, a.petrol, a.id, a.total
ORDER BY a.total asc, 
AVG(c.rating) desc
```

This adds a GROUP BY on the columns in your services table so you will get one row per services/dealer.